# AttributeError: 'CrawlerProcess' object has no attribute 'install'

Tags: python, django, scrapy, celery

I'm trying to run a Scrapy crawl process with Celery. I've looked through a lot of tutorials and this is how everyone seems to do it, but it doesn't work for me:

tasks.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scraper.ubuntu_scraper.ubuntu_spider import UbuntuSpider
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

# this will run every minute
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour="*", minute="*", day_of_week="*"))
def crawl():
    crawler = DomainCrawlerScript()
    return crawler.crawl()

class DomainCrawlerScript():
    def __init__(self):
        self.crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        self.crawler.install()
        self.crawler.configure()
    def _crawl(self):
        self.crawler.crawl(UbuntuSpider)
        self.crawler.start()
        self.crawler.stop()
    def crawl(self):
        p = Process(target=self._crawl)
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hardware.settings')

app = Celery('hardware', broker = 'django://', include=['scraper.tasks'])
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
```

When I run `python manage.py celeryd -v 2 -B -s celery -E -l INFO -I scraper.tasks` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 238, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 416, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/olyazavr/Moka5/hardware/scraper/tasks.py", line 12, in crawl
    crawler.install()
AttributeError: 'CrawlerProcess' object has no attribute 'install'
```

Answer (score 0):

see how scrapy [crawl command](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/commands/crawl.py#L47) is doing it and do the same:

```
crawler = self.crawler_process.create_crawler()
spider = crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
crawler.crawl(spider)
self.crawler_process.start()
```